# calling dll function from php program

Tags: php

I've made a program in php where i got to call a dll function.. that dll contains some hashcode.. i call this dll's function from vb6 through this code:

```
Private Declare Function GetHash Lib "hashGen.dll" (ByVal tEncode As String) As Long
Private Sub get_Key()
    MsgBox GetHash("hello world")
end sub
```

can anybody tell me how to call this function in PHP?

here's my dll file:
http://www.4shared.com/file/-hdichIS/hashGen.html

thnx..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html) to wrap it in PHP extension and then load it via [dl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible out of the box.

There are dynamically loadable PHP extensions in DLL form, loadable using [`dl()`](http://de.php.net/dl) but I strongly assume they have interfaces and functions speficic to a PHP extension.

Possibilities:

- Build a wrapper EXE that uses the DLL and call the executable
- Turn your DLL into a PHP extension (See @Milan's answer for details)
- Run the DLL on the local system using `rundll` or similar
- Introduce your DLL's functionality as a [COM Object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php)